# Issue in curl connecting with Ip address in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, curl

Dear Supporter,

```
   $data=array(
                                    "themeName"=>"gghg"

                            );

                    $adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl();
                    $adapter->setConfig($curlOption);

                    //instantiate the http client and add set the adapter
                    $client = new Zend_Http_Client("http://50.55.146.221/curl_page.php");
                    $client->setAdapter($adapter);

                    //add the post parameters from our config file (the authentication part)
                    $client->setParameterPost($data);

                    //perform the post, and get the response
                    $response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
```

Error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Uri_Exception' with message 'Invalid URI supplied' in /var/www/html/ursify/Source/ursify.com/library/Zend/Uri/Http.php:
```

I am trying to create client object "$client = new Zend_Http_Client`("http://50.55.146.221/curl_page.php");"`

Where i am doing wrong ? Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems everything fine. I've tested your code and there are no errors except timeout in cUrl call. I've tested with ZF 1.12.7

Comment: trimmed for unwanted white space and hidden characters .Now it's working